# If statement that if two values from input match do something

Tags: javascript

I want to make a Log in form in which user have to enter password "pass" and confirm that password "pass2" and if passwords don't match it should give an alert "pass don't match" and if they match it should alert "pass match", i wrote this but it doesn't work:

```html
<form class="forma">
  <p>Registruj se</p>
  <hr>
  <p id="tekst">Napravi svoj nalog. Besplatno je i traje samo minut.</p><br>
  <input id="ime" type="text" name="ime" value="Ime:" onfocus="this.value=''">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input id="prezime" type="text" name="prezime" value="Prezime:" onfocus="this.value=''"><br><br>
  <input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="Email:" onfocus="this.value=''"><br><br>
  <input id="pass" type="text" name="pass" value="Šifra:" onfocus="this.value=''"><br><br>
  <input id="pass2" type="text" name="pass2" value="Potvrdi šifru:" onfocus="this.value=''"><br><br>
  <input id="dugme" type="button" name="registruj" value="Registruj se">
</form>

<script>
  let pass = document.querySelector("#pass input").value;
  let pass2 = document.querySelector("#pass2 input").value;
  let dugme = document.querySelector("#dugme");
  let forma = document.querySelector(".forma");

  dugme.addEventListener("click", function() {

    if (pass === pass2) {
      alert("pass match");
    } else {
      alert("pass don't match");
    }
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you just need to select id, `input` here is redundant

```
document.querySelector("#pass")
```

Moreover, you must move 2 pass getter in the click event handler, to make sure it's always get the latest passwords to match

```js
let dugme = document.querySelector("#dugme");
let forma = document.querySelector(".forma");

dugme.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let pass = document.querySelector("#pass").value;
  let pass2 = document.querySelector("#pass2").value;

  if (pass === pass2) {
    alert("pass match");
  } else {
    alert("pass don't match");
  }
})
```

```html
<form class="forma">
  <p>Registruj se</p>
  <hr>
  <p id="tekst">Napravi svoj nalog. Besplatno je i traje samo minut.</p><br>
  <input id="ime" type="text" name="ime" value="Ime:" onfocus="this.value=''">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input id="prezime" type="text" name="prezime" value="Prezime:" onfocus="this.value=''"><br><br>
  <input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="Email:" onfocus="this.value=''"><br><br>
  <input id="pass" type="text" name="pass" value="Šifra:" onfocus="this.value=''"><br><br>
  <input id="pass2" type="text" name="pass2" value="Potvrdi šifru:" onfocus="this.value=''"><br><br>
  <input id="dugme" type="button" name="registruj" value="Registruj se">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the statements to get values into the event listener so that you can get the latest values on the button click.
And the query selector is not correct:

```js
dugme.addEventListener("click", function(){
  let pass = document.querySelector("input#pass").value;
  let pass2 = document.querySelector("input#pass2").value;
  
  if (pass === pass2) {
    alert("pass match");
  } else {
    alert("pass don't match");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are using the value key default way

```html
<form class="forma">
       <p>Registruj se</p>
       <hr>
       <p id="tekst">Napravi svoj nalog. Besplatno je i traje samo minut.</p>
       <br>
       <input id="ime" type="text" name="ime" value="Ime:" onfocus="this.value=''">
       <input id="prezime" type="text" name="prezime" value="Prezime:" onfocus="this.value=''"><br><br>
       <input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="Email:" onfocus="this.value=''"><br><br>
       <input id="pass" type="text" name="pass" placeholder="Šifra:" onfocus="this.value=''"><br><br>
       <input id="pass2" type="text" name="pass2" placeholder="Potvrdi šifru:" onfocus="this.value=''"><br><br>
       <input id="dugme" type="button" name="registruj" value="Registruj se">
    </form>
    <script>
       let dugme = document.querySelector("#dugme");
       let forma = document.querySelector(".forma");
       
       dugme.addEventListener("click", function() {
       let pass = document.querySelector("#pass").value;
       let pass2 = document.querySelector("#pass2").value;
         if (pass === pass2) {
           alert("pass match");
         } else {
           alert("pass don't match");
         }
       })
    </script>
```